# does the compiler use instanceof to check if two reference are of the same type?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I was kinda wondering how java compiler works. Does it use instanceof the check if two reference are of the same type at compile time? 
e.g: Super superRef = new Sub();
     Sub subRef = (Sub)superRef;
It is said that in compile time compile will check the if two types on the two sides of the assignment match. I want to know how it is implemented in the compiler.

Comment: Probably something like `typeOfLeftThing.isAssignableFrom(typeOfRightThing)`... which will be a method written as part of the compiler (not part of Java).

Comment: The compiler doesn't have an object to do `instanceof` on.  It doesn't even have the class object that `instanceof` expects as the right-hand argument.  It has internal representations of the classes being referenced by the program being compiled.  A function such as @immibis posits is used to query these internal representations.

Comment: That method actually exists in the public API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29

Comment: It can't. It is compiling the code. Compilation precedes execution.

Comment: @Thilo No, not that one. (Think about it, it couldn't possibly have a Class object yet, because the class hasn't been compiled!)

Comment: @HotLicks It will almost certainly have some object that represents the type of the variable. It just won't be a java.lang.Class instance.

Comment: @immibis - That is correct.  There is some object or collection of objects that represents the variable type, but it is not a java.lang.Class.

Comment: Interesting situation really. For some classes (such as the ones in the JDK) it could have actual Class instances. It certainly has no other way to extract information except from the existing class files. But yeah, for the Java source that is currently compiled, it will probably use some internal object (and not a half-constructed Class instance with just signatures and no implementations or so).

Comment: @Thilo - Actually, it could reference different JDK classes from the ones it's running with.

Answer (score 5):

`instanceof` is a runtime check. The compiler does not use it at compile-time.

Along the same lines, the type cast `(Sub) superRef` will also happen at run-time and not be checked by the compiler (except for precluding impossible cases like casting `String` to `Integer` for example).

The compiler takes the compile-type type information into account. Most importantly, the class file definition of your `Super` and `Sub`. In there, you will have `extends` and `implements` statements. From these, the type hierarchy is built. This information is used to check if types are compatible (and methods and fields exist). If you are looking for a public API that does this, it should be most similar to something like `Super.class.isAssignableFrom(Sub.class)`.

The reason things like `instanceof` and runtime type-casts exist is that not everything can be determined ahead of time.